# Synapse: bulk copy from STAGE to DATAMART

Tags: sql-server, azure

I've fact table with rows count ~1 billions/year (~3 millions/day). ETL loads data into STAGE layer/schema with help of Polybase or COPY INTO. Then I'm copying data from STAGE to DATAMART table with help of `INSERT INTO DATAMART.my_table (<cols>) SELECT (<cols>) FROM STAGE.my_table`.

*What is the best way to do bulk copy from STAGE table to DATAMART in Synapse?*

**[Partition switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition#load-new-data-into-partitions-that-contain-data-in-one-step) ISN'T an option.** That's because the table is too small to be partitioned by a day (can be partitioned by a month only), while ETL is daily. With default [60 distributions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/massively-parallel-processing-mpp-architecture#compute-nodes) Synapse suggest to have 60+ millions of rows per partition.

AFAIK, **current approach**: `INSERT INTO DATAMART.my_table (<cols>) SELECT (<cols>) FROM STAGE.my_table` should have a good performance (no transaction log, CTAS-like). But in the same time it keep data in intermediate state for some time, and requires a burden of defining stored procedures with columns list for each fact.

P.S. *is it a common practice to use intermediate STAGE layer before uploading to a busy DATAMART? Is it necessary if at this point we're loading ony nightly?*